# I have a message for you

Tags: riddle

To get my feet wet in Puzzling here is a small riddle:

> There is a message I must give you.
>
> I, who was next in line,
>
> who have left my brothers to come to your aid.
>
> If you are not ready to heed me, I will wait.
>
> Only do not let me fall before you do.
>
> *What am I?*

Hint 1:

> I can be whatever colour you find me in.

Hint 2:

> I wait in one place, clinging on as long as I am able.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're a

> Sticky note!

"There is a message I must give you."

> They're used to write messages.

"I, who was next in line,"

> Since they come in a pad, you have to use them in order.

"who have left my brothers to come to your aid."

> Same as above, emphasizing that each note has two brothers, one on either side.

"If you are not ready to heed me, I will wait."

> Sticky notes stick to things.

"Only do not let me fall before you do."

> Sticky notes stick to things... until they don't.

Comment: That's the one! Nice work :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea

> Chat notification popups! For desktop apps, specifically.

There is a message I must give you.

> Notifications are usually meant to notify you of something.

I, who was next in line,

> Notifications that show up usually contains the newest messages, the "next in line"

who have left my brothers to come to your aid.

> A notification usually contains just one newest message to notify you, separated from the hundreds of other messages sent earlier.

If you are not ready to heed me, I will wait.

> You don't have to react immediately, it will probably remain there for a while. Apps will also often remind you with a red mark signifying that you have unread notifications.

Only do not let me fall before you do.

> But if you're not fast, then the popup can also go away on its own.. and for most desktops, this happens via the notification "falling" through the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Creative guess! But not correct, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the correct answer isn't this, but I was able to "massage" the clues to fit it, so here goes.

You are a:

> **Mobile phone**

Because:

*There is a message I must give you.*

> Our phones give us information

*I, who was next in line,
who have left my brothers to come to your aid.*

> There were many phones of the same model available (at the time of purchase), and the next available one was the phone picked up, for its owner's use

*If you are not ready to heed me, I will wait.*

> We can ignore a ringing phone, or a phone with messages

*Only do not let me fall before you do.*

> Don't drop that phone! Repairs can be expensive!!
>  However, if you're falling, then worry about saving/safeguarding yourself first, not your phone.

Tenuous, I know. I did warn you :-)

Comment: Indeed not correct, but I like the reasoning! :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess stretches the meaning of a few clues, but is it:

> A parachute?

There is a message I must give you.

> Knowing how to operate a parachute is vitally important, so this message must be given.

I, who was next in line,

> The chute is first thing to deploy of the pack, straps, and cords. Alternatively, parachutes are sometimes hung on rack with many others and the one you select is next in line.

Who have left my brothers to come to your aid.

> When the parachute is deployed, it leaves the bundle of pack, straps, and cords (brothers) and then aids you in decelerating.

If you are not ready to heed me, I will wait.

> The parachute is deployed when you pull the ripcord.

Only do not let me fall before you do.

> If the parachute falls before you do, then you will not have happy landing to say the least.

> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The last one made me laugh :) Sorry, that's not correct though!

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> ski lift?  (specifically, [a chair lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chairlift)?)

There is a message I must give you.

> This is the only line that I can't get.  Perhaps the message is the riddle itself?

I, who was next in line,

> Chair lifts consist of a number of chairs, each attached at even distances to a cable (forming a circular "line").

who have left my brothers to come to your aid.

> As the chair approaches to aid the skiier (or snowboarder) up the mountain, it appears to be far away from the other chairs on the lift.

If you are not ready to heed me, I will wait.

> There is some time between when one chair leaves and the next arrives to scoop up a new set of skiiers.

Only do not let me fall before you do.

> If you sit down (allow yourself to "fall") but the chair lift has already left (this can involve "falling" somewhat as the lift entrance is often on an elevated platform), you'll be in trouble!

Comment: Sorry, that's not it!